# Bluetooth headset automatically connects and then disconnects until explicitly connected

Tags: bluetooth, pulseaudio, 20.04, alsa, pavucontrol

I have reinstalled pulsaudio, pavucontrol and also pulseaudio-module-bluetooth. But none of the solutions seem to work. I get the error pa_context_connect() failed: Connection refused whenever I type the commands

```
sudo pactl unload-module module-bluetooth-discover 

sudo pactl load-module module-bluez5-discover
```

I added the MAC address of the bluetooth to trusted devices via bluetoothctl. But it doesnt work
The continuous connection and disconnections frustrates me a lot. The headphones work well with android devices and with Windows 10 (On the same PC). I do not see any changes in output when I execute

```
journalctl -f
```

(Both with/without sudo).

The output of journalctl -f

```
Jun 08 19:50:01 adonis CRON[155600]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
Jun 08 19:50:01 adonis CRON[155600]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
Jun 08 19:50:06 adonis dbus-daemon[4361]: [system] Rejected send message, 0 matched rules; type="method_return", sender=":1.208" (uid=1000 pid=128755 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --daemonize=no --log-target=jo" label="unconfined") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination=":1.4" (uid=0 pid=4358 comm="/usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd " label="unconfined")
Jun 08 19:50:06 adonis gsd-media-keys[19578]: Unable to get default sink
Jun 08 19:50:06 adonis acpid[4354]: input device has been disconnected, fd 20
Jun 08 19:50:06 adonis /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[17606]: (II) config/udev: removing device OPPO Enco M31 (AVRCP)
Jun 08 19:50:06 adonis /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[17606]: (**) Option "fd" "91"
Jun 08 19:50:06 adonis /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[17606]: (II) event18 - OPPO Enco M31 (AVRCP): device removed
Jun 08 19:50:06 adonis /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[17606]: (II) UnloadModule: "libinput"
Jun 08 19:50:06 adonis /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[17606]: (II) systemd-logind: releasing fd for 13:82
Jun 08 19:50:13 adonis gnome-shell[17887]: ../clutter/clutter/clutter-actor.c:10548: The clutter_actor_set_allocation() function can only be called from within the implementation of the ClutterActor::allocate() virtual function.
```

**Btw, Oppo Enco M31 is the bluetooth headset.**

On executing bluetoothctl, this is the output:

```
[CHG] Device MACADDRESS Connected: yes
[CHG] Device MACADDRESS Connected: no
[CHG] Device MACADDRESS Connected: yes
[CHG] Device MACADDRESS Connected: no
[CHG] Device MACADDRESS Connected: yes
[CHG] Device MACADDRESS Connected: no
```

Which will go on forever until the headsets connect to another device in the vicinity.

However If I go to the bluetooth settings and explicitly select "connect", I will be able to connect to the headset.

Any idea on how I can automatically connect to the PC once it is paired?

Operating System: Ubuntu 20.04
Kernel: 5.4.0-33-generic